# Can't connect to Cosmos DB Mongo 3.6 compatibility from Robo 3T

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, robo3t, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I just set up a Mongo 3.6 compatible Cosmos DB.  I can connect to the account using the Mongo command line. I've followed the instructions on the Cosmos site, but Robo 3T won't connect.  I see the following when I hit the "test" button in the connection modal.

```
"Authorization failed on admin database as my-cosmos-test"
```

To be clear, the correct credentials are in the provided connection URL.

If I hit the "show error details" link in Robo 3T, it says "Error: File name too long".

[image]

My (redacted) connection string looks like:

```
mongodb://my-cosmos-test:mypasswordishere==@my-cosmos-test.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb&maxIdleTimeMS=120000&appName=@my-cosmos-test@
```

I tried pulling the appName off the end but no dice.

I tried the same connection string in Mongo Compass. This did actually connect and I was able to create a database/collection, but it was not fully functional.  It would fail to list my collections.

Is there a solution for Robo 3T or another client that works reasonably well (other than the command line)?

Answer (score 0):

Doh...it was my own idiocy. I was putting the entire connection string in the Robo3T Address field instead of just the root address:

```
my-cosmos-test.mongo.cosmos.azure.com
```

After that it worked...